# How to add a certain time to a datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, int

I want to add hours to a `datetime` and use:

```
date = date_object + datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
```

Now I want to add a time:
 `time='-7:00'` (string) plus 4 hours.

I tried `hours=time+4` but this doesn't work. I think I have to `int` the string like `int(time)` but this doesn't work either.

Comment: You answered your own question sort of.  `time` is a `str`, so adding an `int` to it wouldn't do anything.  Instead, you need to convert `time` to a `datetime` object and then add to it like in your example.

Comment: you mean time2=datetime(time) ? When I do this there comes the error: 'module' object is not callable.

Comment: I added an answer for you to use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert to a datetime object in order to add timedelta to your current time, then return it back to just the time portion.

Using `date.today()` just uses the arbitrary current date and sets the time to the time you supply.  This allows you to add over days and reset the clock to 00:00.

`dt.time()` prints out the result you were looking for.

```py
from datetime import date, datetime, time, timedelta

dt = datetime.combine(date.today(), time(7, 00)) + timedelta(hours=4)
print dt.time()
```

**Edit:**
To get from a string `time='7:00'` to what you could split on the colon and then reference each.

```py
this_time = this_time.split(':')   # make it a list split at :
this_hour = this_time[0]
this_min = this_time[1]
```

**Edit 2:**
To put it all back together then:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime, time, timedelta

this_time = '7:00'

this_time = this_time.split(':')   # make it a list split at :
this_hour = int(this_time[0])
this_min = int(this_time[1])

dt = datetime.combine(date.today(), time(this_hour, this_min)) + timedelta(hours=4)
print dt.time()
```

If you already have a full date to use, as mentioned in the comments, you should convert it to a datetime using [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#datetime.datetime.strptime).  I think another answer walks through how to use it so I'm not going to put an example.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I convert '7:00' to 7,00?

Comment: Added a way to do that.

Comment: Can I use a initial datetime like initial_datetime='2015-11-03 08:05:22' instead of date.today()? And there is a error:" 'str' object is not callable" in the datetime.combine line.

Comment: @Torb you can use the `strptime` method of `datetime` module for parsing your input time

Comment: You would need to `int()` your times from a string to an integer to use them, I should have mentioned that.  And yes, you can use a specific datetime instead, which would make more sense.  I was under the assumption you had no actual date to use and therefore using today is just an arbitrary date to assign so that time acts like a time.

Answer (score 1):

Better you parse your time like below and access datetime attributes for getting time components from the parsed datetime object

```
 input_time = datetime.strptime(yourtimestring,'yourtimeformat')
 input_seconds = input_time.second # for seconds
 input_minutes = input_time.minute # for minutes
 input_hours = input_time.hour     # for hours
 # Usage: input_time = datetime.strptime("07:00","%M:%S")
```

Rest you have `datetime.timedelta` method to compose the duration.

```
new_time = initial_datetime + datetime.timedelta(hours=input_hours,minutes=input_minutes,seconds=input_seconds)
```

See docs [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)
and [datetime format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)